# Pandas nlargest plus always include "X"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a graph where I list the top 4 brands, plus the brand I represent ("X"), by the sum of all of their products rank.

Below is an example of 3 brands and what the data would look like (there are over 300 brands in my dataset).

```
Brand | Product | Rank
  A   |    P1   |   1000
      |    P2   |   1210
      |    P3   |   2000
      |    P4   |   600
      |    P5   |   756
      |    P6   |   867
  B   |    P1   |   549
      |    P2   |   1572
      |    P3   |   3490
      |    P4   |   2341
      |    P5   |   431
      |    P6   |   321
  C   |    P1   |   421
      |    P2   |   121
      |    P3   |   805
      |    P4   |   1202
      |    P5   |   4032
      |    P6   |   432
```

How can I select the top 4 brands, based on the sum of their products' rank, and then always include my brand, brand "X"?

Also, in the event that my brand is in the top 4 brands, how can I then select the top 5 brands so that I have a constant of 5 brands in each graph?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `pd.concat`

```
n=2# input the number you need 
x='A' # input the brand you want to keep 
pd.concat([df.sum(level=0).sort_values('Rank',ascending=False).head(2),df.sum(level=0).loc[[x]]]).max(level=0)
Out[456]: 
       Rank
Brand      
B      8704
C      7013
A      6433
```

Comment: How is this specifying that is should get the sum of the rank? I am still new to python but it doesn't seem to be specifying the "rank" column or [2].

Comment: `df.rank.sum(level=0)` you can add this

Comment: In trying to implement this, I noticed that the code isn't actually returning the correct brands. 

The top 2 brands in my sample data above are actually brand B and C, not A. The sample code you provided, however, outputs A...thus I don't believe the sum is working properly. 

Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: @Dys_Lexi_A my bad, adding sort_values should solve the problem

Comment: One final (hopefully) question. 

It looks like when I add in more brands, and Brand "A" that I want in is within the top 5, this doesn't work. 

Ie, if there was a Brand D with 1000 and a Brand E with 1200, the results will show B, C, A and not display D and E. 

I am running this multiple times with multiple slices of the data and was hoping to have one line that would work whether Brand A was in the top 5 or not.

Comment: @Dys_Lexi_A sorry when I change my code forget change the hard coding 'A' to x